# nameserver cache

Tags: domain-name-system

I am going the change nameservers of my domain. I know there is nameserver cache issue, but I want to know how the cache affects my visitors. I am not changing ip of my server, so no matter which nameserver they use, they should be able to find my server. Is it true?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take care to replicate the records exactly, then it will not affect your users at all.  Many providers will let you export your "zone file" so it can be reimported elsewhere.  If this is an option, it would save you some typing and help avoid possible typos.

Comment: Thank you. I only have a few record, so it's easy to manually enter, although Godaddy provide export.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ensure that the new nameservers are updated with the appropriate records to point your visitors to your server. To avoid any down-time, this is best done before you change the nameservers over. That way, although there will be a period when some users will be getting their answers from a mix of the two servers (due to caching techniques as you say), it won't be an issue, as both sets of nameservers will return the correct answer.

Comment: Good info. But can only set one as answer, and I gave it to jamieb already. Thank you, too.